# How to pass props on mapped array of routes in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How do you pass props on a mapped array of routes? let say you have more than 5 links and you just want to make each route as an object in an array inside your routes component, assuming every needed component is imported, here's my RouteList component:

```
const routeList = [
  {
    path:"/",
    render: props => (<Home {...props} users={users} deleteUser={props.deleteUser} />)
  },
  {
    path:"/about",
    component:"About"
  }, etc];

class RouteList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const routeComponents = routelists.map(
      ({ path, component, render }, key) => (
        <Route
          exact
          path={path}
          component={component}
          render={render}
          key={key}
        />
      )
    );
    return <div>{routeComponents}</div>;
  }
}

export default RouteList;
```

As you can see i added the render as an object property to the home route so i could include the props. Now in my App.js i imported the RouteList above like this:

```
import RouteList from "./components/routelist";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    UniqueId.enableUniqueIds(this);
    this.state = {
      users: [
        { id: this.nextUniqueId(), name: "Louise", age: 28 },
        { id: this.nextUniqueId(), name: "Karen", age: 24 },
        { id: this.nextUniqueId(), name: "Jared", age: 32 },
        { id: this.nextUniqueId(), name: "Noime", age: 28 }
      ]
    };
    this.deleteUser = this.deleteUser.bind(this);
  }

  deleteUser = (index, e) => {
    const { users } = this.state;
    const newUsers = Object.assign([], users);
    newUsers.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({
      users: newUsers
    });
  };
  render() {
    const { users } = this.state;
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Navigation />
          <main>
            <Switch>
              <RouteList users={users} />
            </Switch>
          </main>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

I get a reference error: users is not defined in the RouteList component. or the Type error: "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined".

Here's my Home component:

```
import React from "react";
import Users from "../users";

const HomePage = props => {
  return (
    <div className="contentContainer">
      <header className="pageHeader">
        <h1>Home</h1>
      </header>
      <ul id="user-list">
        {props.users.map((user, index) => {
          return (
            <Users
              age={user.age}
              key={user.id}
              index={index}
              deleteEvent={props.deleteUser}
            >
              {user.name}
            </Users>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 2):

move this inside render method.

```
const routelists = [
  {
    path: "/",
    render: props => (
      <Home {...props} users={this.props.user} deleteUser={props.deleteUser} />
    )
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    component: About
  }
];
```

Comment: const users = {...this.state.users}

Comment: still the same errors, here's my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/6yy37lly5k

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to use props in the routeList array,but you wont be able to access props outside of the class declaration, this is what the constructor/super method is for.

You have also not declared routelists anywhere, so there is nothing to map.

Try something like this:

```
 import Home from ....
 class RouteList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const routelists = [
      {
        path:"/",
        render: props => (<Home {...this.props} users={this.props.users} 
        deleteUser={this.props.deleteUser} />)
      },
      {
        path:"/about",
        component:"About"
      }, etc];

    const routeComponents = routelists.map(
      ({ path, component, render }, key) => (
        <Route
          exact
          path={path}
          component={component}
          render={render}
          key={key}
        />
      )
    );
    return <div>{routeComponents}</div>;
  }
}

export default RouteList;
```

Comment: i tried that but i get "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" , also i already imported Home and the other page components into the RouteList component.